# How do I import JSON file data into JS file and output the JSON data in JS console?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a list of data in my JSON file. I am trying to output certain strings and arrays from my JSON file via my JS. How do I go on about this? All these files are saved on my desktop.

I've tried Xhttp code. But I think I need some server going on for that, and I don't have that. Also, I'm pretty sure this should be possible without having to use a server?
PS: the json file is named: movie.json

```
 JSON CODE
    {
    "movie": {
    "name": "drive",
    "year": "2011",
    "people": {
        "actors": [
            {
                "name": "ryan gosling"
            },
            {
                "name": "cary mulligan"
            },
            {
                "name": "bryan cranston"
            }
        ]
    }
    }
    }


    JS CODE
    function preload() {
      var movie = load.JSON("movie.json");
    }


    function(movie) {
        var movie = JSON.parse(movie);
        console.log(movie[0].name);
        console.log(movie[0].year);
        console.log(movie[0].actors);
    }();
```

drive, 2011, ryan gosling, cary mulligan, bryan cranston

Comment: Are you saying you want your browser to be able to open this JSON file... on your local drive? and read the contents? If so, that sort of behavior is blocked, for very good security reasons. Would you want every website you visit to be able to access files on your local drive via JavaScript?

Comment: I'm not sure. Are you saying that I HAVE to run JSON code through a server for security reasons?

Comment: If you need to access a separate JSON file, then yes. However would it be possible for you to just copy the contents of the JSON file directly into your HTML file that you're opening in the browser? That might be a much simpler approach. Otherwise yes, you're going to need to set up a localhost web server.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. I'll try to work some more with xhttp then, and set up a server. I probably need to learn it that way anyway. Do you knowhow I end this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var movie;
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhhtp.open( "GET", "movie.json", true);

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {

        movie = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
    }

}

http.send();


console.log(movie[0].name);
console.log(movie[0].year);
console.log(movie[0].actors);
```

I do not know if the code above will help you. Using XMLHttpRequest will help you fetch the json file then you can parse and sort into array. Note: you do not need a server to use XMLHttpRequest, if you have text editor like VSCode you can us it to run live HTML codes then you can get the full link to the JSON file you want to parse e.g localhost:9000/movie.json